# Endianness - Ordered When?

Tags: assembly, endianness

I get the general concept of endianness, but I'm a little fuzzy on the mechanics of how and when it comes to be. I have this assembly example for Intel x64:

```
section .data

newline_char: db 10
codes: db '0123456789abcdef'

section .text
global _start

print_newline:
    mov rax, 1          ; 'write' syscall identifier
    mov rdi, 1          ; 'stdout' file descriptor
    mov rsi, newline_char   ; starting address of data
    mov rdx, 1          ; number of bytes to write
    syscall
      ret

print_hex:
    mov rax, rdi        ; move input (rdi) to rax
    mov rdi, 1          ; 'stdout' file descriptor
    mov rdx, 1          ; number of bytes to write
    mov rcx, 64         ; bit/position counter

iterate:
    push    rax         ; save input, rax altered later
    sub rcx, 4          ; every iteration shifts 4 fewer
    sar rax, cl         ; shift rax 'cl' times (cl is lowest byte of rcx)
    and rax, 0xf        ; 'AND' rax with 0xf to preserve lowest 4 bits
    lea rsi, [codes + rax]  ; add value of rax to address of codes

    mov rax, 1          ; 'write' syscall identifier (prepare to write)
    push    rcx         ; 'write' syscall alters rcx (counter) (rcx caller saved)

    syscall

    pop rcx         ; restore counter
    pop rax         ; restore original input

    test    rcx, rcx        ; rcx & rcx -> (set flags)
    jnz iterate         ; if not zero, load 'iterate' to RIP

      ret


section .data
demo1: dq 0x1122334455667788
demo2: db 0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x50, 0x60, 0x70, 0x80

section .text

_start:
    mov rdi, [demo1]
    call    print_hex
    call    print_newline

    mov rdi, [demo2]
    call    print_hex
    call    print_newline

    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

When I run this, as is, I get `1122334455667788` and `8070605040302010`

So, I'm a little confused at this point, because I would have thought that `88` and `80` would both be stored in the first memory address.

At this point, I'm thinking that if I leave the labeled values the same and change from 64 bit `rax` register to 32 bit `eax` register, I will get `11223344` and `80706050`. But, I get `11223344` and `40302010`.

If I'm still storing the same 8 bytes using `db` in `demo2` should I get the same least significant bytes first?

And, why isn't `demo1` printing in reverse order? Does endianness only apply to bytes stored individual?

Comment: The assembler you use also knows that your processor is little-endian.  So when you use `dq`, it knows that 88 is the little end and should be stored first.  When you use `db` it can no longer help and now the byte order matters, 10 is the little end.  When you use eax instead of rax then the register is no longer capable of representing the four bytes at the big end, they just vanished.  Nothing special happened.

Comment: So if `dq` stores with `88` at the little end, why doesn't printing beginning at that memory address produce `88776655` ?

Comment: Because your code specifically prints in big endian? You start from the most significant nibble.

Comment: Your print_hex code is not broken, it knows that the big end needs to printed first.  So SAR shifts by 60 bits the first time through the loop.  Endiness plays no role in that code.

Comment: *facepalm* /me walks away in shame

Comment: If you change it to `eax`, you should get for demo1 `55667788`, not `11223344`??? (as the memory content at `demo1` is `88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11` and memory content at `demo2` is `10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80`. (check the listing file from assembler, and also load it in debugger and check memory view vs content of `rax/eax` after fetch). (and rather don't rely on `print` for debugging purposes, just find some nice debugger which suits you (`gdb` or `edb-debugger` are two quite different options, one should work for you).

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can figure out `gdb` and report back. I'll post a full answer to my question after I get it worked out.

Comment: To clarify, endianness is arranged when the data is _STORED_ into memory?

Comment: @NonSecwitter - endianness affects both reading and writing of data from and to memory. X86 has a swap instruction that can reverse the byte ordering. For xmm registers, there are shuffle instructions can can also reorder data.

Comment: @ped7g you're right. I forgot that I had split demo1 into two 32 bit values to avoid the data bounds warning. I reassembled with the full 64 bit and get 55667788